# Finding optimal rectangle overlaping a polygon

Tags: geometry

I have a general convex polygon with four vertices.
I'm looking for a way to find an axes aligned rectangle that is optimally overlapping the polygon.
I have prefer optimality has maximal intersection over union (Jaccard) measure, but other measures for optimality are also possible.

So far, I came across [Calculating the area and centroid of a polygon](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/) which shows an easy way of calculating the centroid and 2nd moments of a general polygon, and [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_moment_of_area#Rectangle_with_centroid_at_the_origin) that shows a closed formula for the 2nd moment of origin centered axes aligned rectangle, so I can generate a rectangle that has the same centroid and 2nd moments as the polygon, **but is this rectangle optimal in any way?**

Comment: Why, it is surely optimal if we define optimality via the deviation of centroid and 2nd moments. As for the maximum intersection solution, that would be the rectangle which covers the whole polygon, wouldn't it?

Comment: @IvanNeretin As for the optimality - it is true that if I define my solution as optimal it will be optimal - though I'm not sure how related is it in extreme cases to the Jaccard measure.
I'm looking for maximal __intersection over union__ measure. In that case there might be better solutions than the enclosing rectangle, as can be seen [here] (https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*k0yeYxJsv2eXlLiduyLLrA.png)

Comment: Here is the correct link for the jaccard example: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1%2Ak0yeYxJsv2eXlLiduyLLrA.png

Comment: Oh, I got you. Indeed, (intersection/union) is a different measure than just intersection. Well, there is not much to be said. Jaccard measure will give you one rectangle, centroid+moments will give another. Generally speaking, I don't expect them to have anything in common.